# Fazer um POST com JSON - HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

To precisando fazer um PostAsync na minha web-api, passando um JSON como parâmetro. Tentei da seguinte forma, mas não tive sucesso até agora... Independente da estrutura desse JSON, eu recebo um Bad Request na hora de executar o post.

Alguém consegue me dizer o que está faltando neste código?

```
var url = "URL";

http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));

JArray array = new JArray();
JValue title = new JValue(drive.result.NAME);
JValue fileContent = new JValue(base64);
JValue entityId = new JValue(idNegocio);

array.Add(title);
array.Add(fileContent);
array.Add(entityId);

string JSON = array.ToString();

var parametro = new StringContent(JSON.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var post = await http.PostAsJsonAsync(url, parametro);

if (post.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return "Sucesso!";
}
else
{
    return post.Content.ToString();
}
```

O JSON tem que ter uma estrutura parecida com :

```
{
    "fields": {
        "title": "a",
        "fileContent": "b",
        "entityId": "c"
    }
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse artigo: http://www.macoratti.net/16/11/c_webreq1.htm